# How Can I Count the Number of Times that Different Values Occur in a Column if the Possible Values Are Not Known?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Given the table of items

```
                  id                  |       lccnumber        |               libraryid
--------------------------------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------
 d6f7c1ba-a237-465e-94ed-f37e91bc64bd | PR6056.I4588           | 5d78803e-ca04-4b4a-aeae-2c63b924518b
 1714f71f-b845-444b-a79e-a577487a6f7d | RC60 .A5               | 5d78803e-ca04-4b4a-aeae-2c63b924518b
 1b6d3338-186e-4e35-9e75-1b886b0da53e | PR6056.I4588           | 5d78803e-ca04-4b4a-aeae-2c63b924518b
 4428a37c-8bae-4f0d-865d-970d83d5ad55 | PR6056.I4588           | c2549bb4-19c7-4fcc-8b52-39e612fb7dbe
 7212ba6a-8dcf-45a1-be9a-ffaa847c4423 | TK5105.88815 .A58 2004 | 5d78803e-ca04-4b4a-aeae-2c63b924518b
 100d10bf-2f06-4aa0-be15-0b95b2d9f9e3 | TK5105.88815 .A58 2004 | c2549bb4-19c7-4fcc-8b52-39e612fb7dbe
```

is there a SQL query that will produce the result set

```
       lccnumber        | 5d78803e-ca04-4b4a-aeae-2c63b924518b | c2549bb4-19c7-4fcc-8b52-39e612fb7dbe
------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
 PR6056.I4588           |                   2                  |                    1
 RC60 .A5               |                   1                  |                    0
 TK5105.88815 .A58 2004 |                   1                  |                    1
```

If the possible `libraryid`s are known ahead of time, then I could do something like

```
SELECT lccNumber,
       SUM(CASE WHEN libraryId = 5d78803e-ca04-4b4a-aeae-2c63b924518b THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS 5d78803e-ca04-4b4a-aeae-2c63b924518b,
       SUM(CASE WHEN libraryId = c2549bb4-19c7-4fcc-8b52-39e612fb7dbe THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS c2549bb4-19c7-4fcc-8b52-39e612fb7dbe
FROM items
GROUP BY lccNumber;
```

but I am looking for a solution in the case that they are *not* known ahead of time. One approach that would probably work is to first query for the possible `libraryId`s and then programmatically construct a `SELECT` clause that accounts for all of these values, but I am wondering if there is a simpler or more efficient way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the values on separate *rows*:

```
SELECT lccNumber, libraryId, COUNT(*)
FROM items
GROUP BY lccNumber, libraryId;
```

Then re-arrange them at the application layer.  You can combine these into records and aggregate into an array for each `lccNumber`:

```
SELECT lccNumber, ARRAY_AGG( (libraryId, cnt) )
FROM (SELECT lccNumber, libraryId, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM items
      GROUP BY lccNumber, libraryId
     ) l
GROUP BY lccNumber
```

Comment: I don't think that putting the values on separate rows would be very viable solution due to how the data is being used at the application layer, but using `ARRAY_AGG` is an interesting idea that I will look into. Thanks!